# Awk syntax with printf - not desired format

Tags: string, awk, printf

I'm having some difficulty determining where my syntax is wrong with an awk statement.  My data looks like this:

```
AAAA777
AAADMD
AAAEEE
AAALAWN
AAAMAN
AAA7777
```

I want the output to be left justified, padded to 8 total characters, plus a couple of add-ons at the end.  The desired output would look like:

```
AAAA777 ZC#8
AAADMD  ZC#8
```

Instead what I'm getting looks like:

```
ZC#8777
 ZC#8D
 ZC#8E
ZC#8AWN
 ZC#8N
ZC#8777
```

My awk statement looks like this:

```
awk '{ printf "%-8.8s%2.2s%2s\n",$0,"ZC","#8" }' file.txt
```

It seems backward and it's not the desired character count. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your file has DOS/Windows line endings.  I created file.txt without them and it worked fine:

```
$ awk '{ printf "%-8.8s%2.2s%2s\n",$0,"ZC","#8" }' file.txt
AAAA777 ZC#8
AAADMD  ZC#8
AAAEEE  ZC#8
AAALAWN ZC#8
AAAMAN  ZC#8
AAA7777 ZC#8
```

However, if I convert the line endings to DOS, then I get the output that you see:

```
$ unix2dos <file.txt >file.dos
$ awk '{ printf "%-8.8s%2.2s%2s\n",$0,"ZC","#8" }' file.dos
ZC#8777
 ZC#8D
 ZC#8E
ZC#8AWN
 ZC#8N
ZC#8777
```

Unless you want to keep the DOS line endings, the straightforward solution is to remove them with any of the usual utilities, such as `dos2unix` or `tr`.

Alternatively, use awk's record separator, `RS`, to remove the unneeded carriage return:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '{ printf "%-8.8s%2.2s%2s\n",$0,"ZC","#8" }' file.dos
AAAA777 ZC#8
AAADMD  ZC#8
AAAEEE  ZC#8
AAALAWN ZC#8
AAAMAN  ZC#8
AAA7777 ZC#8
```

Comment: Brilliant -- that was it exactly.  Works perfectly!